# Apache Rewrite URL

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I had my document `DocumentRoot` set to `www/fg`. 
Before, I did browse to `www/fg` by typing `http://www.mydomain.com/www/fg`.

Then, I set up `VirtualHosts` that point to `www/fg`. And now I just type `http://www.mydomain.com`.

The problem is that my web developer wrote links as `www/fg/image.png`.
And thos links are not accessable anymore.
There is a way to tell apache to rewrite any link like `http://www.mydomain.com/www/fg/image.png to http://www.mydomain.com/image.png?`

I would also change links like `http://www.mydomain/www/fg/somelink` to `http://www.mydomain.com/somelink`.

Same for https.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add alias in apache virtualhost which can make your images accessible with same link.

```
Alias /www/fg/ /var/www/fg/
```

Replace "/var/www/" with your DocumentRoot path.

Comment: thank you. I forgot to mention that I would also change links like http://www.mydomain/www/fg/somelink to http://www.mydomain.com/somelink.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to replace all the links in the content with the correct versions.

However, during transition period, you can use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/www/fg(.+)$ http://www.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, if a user accesses http://www.mydomain.com/www/fg/anylink, he will be 301 redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/anylink.